# Need help with UV Unwrapping a gun model

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I am struggling to unWrapp this weapon model I have created. I am struggling on where to put the seams and the general work flow and direction of unwrapping and how I am meant to do this. I want to be able to put this into substance painter to bake but to do that I need a UV layout with good textel space. How would I go about this? 
I have also tried to smart unwrap but get bad results when using that method.
[image]

Here is the blend file. [File](http://drive.google.com/open?id=152SMAeMTtap8r4NDJLUGPTsuh7J5XlgC)

Comment: Hmm. You should try to reduce the number of vertices. I can see a lot of useless vertices in your mesh. For example, the part near the canon doesn't need that much of vertices. Try to reduce it and Smart UV, you should get something abit better... Of course using seams is a better way to unwrap it. Can you publish your blend file (Can't acess it :/)  ?

Comment: Here sorry about that https://drive.google.com/open?id=152SMAeMTtap8r4NDJLUGPTsuh7J5XlgC

Comment: what version of blender 2.8 you use ? this blue lines what is ?, i can't delete or clear this lines, i use 2.81

Comment: Wow, the topology is very bad, too sad where it is not needed, you should start repairing the apology, but not in the way that the answer they gave you is bad enough, it is the same or worse than yours, at least you respect the quads , but not correctly, I will give you an example and when you have repaired it I will tell you how to make your uv for this type of mesh models that represent weapons, and its UV is very bad

Comment: Its topology is so bad that I do not review this very serious error that you have and this affects your texturing because enzymes will be wrong your UV and you will not know where the error is [Error](https://i.imgur.com/n7jYu1C.png)

Comment: [Good topoligy](https://i.imgur.com/W55RjXG.png) - [a better view and finish for hard edge parts](https://i.imgur.com/4aBxzAZ.png)

Comment: If you want to model weapons, ty to inspire yourself from the csgo obj files. They are really well made and they don't use NGONS. https://imgur.com/USdWZCV mp7 from csgo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First clean and make a good Tology

[image: Good Tology]

### in edit mode select all

[image: Unwrap]

### Use Unwrap Project

[image: smart uv project]
[image]

### use Pack Islands to make a better Uv map

[image: pack islands]
[image]
[image]

### Traditional Method:

the result and quality will depend on your ability to develop the model, there is no specific rule or forced technique, it really is adaptive to your needs and the completeness of the model

### Mark Seams according to your model

[image: mark seams]

Select UNWRAP

[image: UNWRAP]
[image]
[image]

small strokes of hand paint for texturing sample

[image: hand paint]

### Feedback Blend file

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you don't try to arrange your mesh aswell. If you want to import the mesh in a game engine, it will automatically triangulate everything. (especially the dents). If you keep only one face that is supposed to be connected to tons of vertices, you'll just get a really bad result. Our technique is way different and it seems that you lack also some blender workflow technique. I know that my topology is bad because I wanted to show somewhere to start. You did not use any mirror modifier which is just unbelievable when it comes to modeling for games...

Comment: uso unity desde hace 5 años y otros motores de juego, no hay mucho que puedas enseñarme, tengo 3 juegos publicados y mas de 30 apps en play store

Comment: its lack of experience in the field is noted since it does not even know how this topology is made nor is it capable of understanding it through the uv map

Comment: In addition to this, this is not a place to teach, it is simply to answer questions, if you want a modeling course go to blender org and look for professionals like blendertus.es

Comment: Wow. I have learned alot here and I appreciate the time you have taken to help me out and laying it out in a way that is easy to understand but from what i have learned is that ngons are bad and you want to aviod them or is this not the case for hard surfacing? Hopefully the key points you have shown me are: 
1. Break down the model into parts.
2. Clean the topology of the model.
3. Use modifers when I can. 

I am sorry if I have annoyed you in anyway from asking the question and the blue lines are bevel weights used for the bevel modifer and subsurf for sharp edges instead of loopcuts.

Comment: @railgun3000 no problem, if it served you mark it as accepted, ask for the blue borders because I haven't used much 2.8, this is my first long moment in 2.8 and honestly I don't like the interface is very ugly and quite uncomfortable, I develop some things in 2.79b on my own fork, I like more than 2.8, it does very good things 2.8 but the interface is a problem

Comment: @railgun3000 I leave you the feedback blend so you can follow the example, it will help you a lot

Comment: Ngons are in no way better than topology shown in the question which is not good as well. They will lead to quite visible errors when baking (if any) and visible errors in triangulating in the game. I'd suggect you to cool down in qualifying topology as "very bad" and others' answers as those which "have no basis".

Comment: so far a comment neither basis nor fundamentals, you only complain, but you contribute nothing, so as he created on the left with your cemetery @MrZak You are also one of the expert todologists here who usually criticize as an agitator and not contribute? NGONS, hehe ngons end up being converted into tris like everything else, the difference is in how skilled you are to handle them

Comment: *but you contribute nothing* neither do you with your useless estimatings of others work. *ngons end up being converted into tris* correct although has been already mentioned in comments here, nothing new here. *difference is in how skilled you are to handle them* yes but you write nothing about that and mention nothing about possible problems and solutions in your answer. One who isn't familiar with that can learn the hidden stone only by searching for it by himself, not from your answer. No point in this discussion; if you have any opinion regarding the question, prove it in your answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the first thing I did:

- Add a mirror modifier
- Reduce your mesh polygon count

I did not Unwrap your model as I think that It should something you got to learn (not using the smart UV method). But your mesh should be better at this point.
Try to use as much blender modifier as possible. it is only when you want to export your mesh that you make a copy of it and apply all the modifiers.

[image]

[image]

Second advice is to thin when modeling to optimize your mesh a first time (just simple things) then pass a second time on it to check where you could improve it.

As an advice for the UV, you should try to isolate the cube areas and mark the seams (red):
[image]

Anyway, that was a long work and you still have some on this model but this is just detailing, especially the cube areas. If it as model for an FPS, you should consider deleting the faces that won't be visible for the player.
If it is a multiplayer model, you should consider the previous advice and create a low poly model to render instead of the high poly one

Good luck :D

https://we.tl/t-GxxdSrGEk5

Comment: Your modeling is debatable in my opinion is very bad and your councils have no basis, they are inefficient just like your technique

Comment: you don't even know how to write, you have terrible spelling mistakes and you want to criticize me for a workflow, I remind you that advertising links are not allowed, so edit your question and your bad spelling, so if you do not accept the issue I will mark you a flag , points will be subtracted and they will also punish you that they will be checking you all the time