# UV layout doesn't match shape of the object

Tags: uv

I created a cube and made it sort of rectangular. When I tried to UV map it, this is what it looked like:

[image]

As you can see in the UV layout, all the faces of the mesh are being represented as squares. I was hoping that the dimension of the faces would be more similar to the actual faces in the mesh, i.e. more rectangular.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Probably the objet is scaled. In object mode, apply the scale.

Comment: But that's what I already did. I was in object mode when I made the cube rectangular. And then I went to edit mode to mark the seams.

Comment: OK, but in object mode, have you tried using Ctrl+A then 'scale' (apply scale)?

Comment: No, I just pressed the N key to open the Transform window. Then I changed the scale value from there.

Comment: That's the reason, but you now have a plain answer about it.

Comment: @User95 check this and apply to your model [Mark Seams according to your model](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/147305/58715)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you have edited the object and didn't apply the scaling. If so, you have to apply the changes for your particular editing transformations such as Scaling and Rotating.

- Go to the *Object* mode
- Use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and select an option.

This will apply your transformation changes to the object by setting the *Scale* to `(1,1,1)` and *Rotation* to `(0,0,0)`.

[See the documentation](http://Mode:%20Object%20Mode%20Menu:%20Object%20%E2%80%A3%20Apply%20%E2%80%A3%20Hotkey:%20Ctrl-A)

Scaling object and UV Unwrap without applying transformation changes:

[image]

After applying changes:

[image]

Comment: But can't I hit the N key (to open the Transform window) and directly change the scaling from there? Because I actually need precise values. Why is that different from scaling the object by selecting it with A?

Answer (score 3):

A complement to [@firat](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/58050/firat) answer which is good (and in response of the question you've added in comments).

When you scale an object, for instance this:

[image]

Internally, it keeps the same sizes:

[image]

Because internally, vertices positions haven't changed, they are just stretched from the outside.

And in some circumstances this has an impact: this is the case concerning the UV maps (as the UV maps are at vertex level).

Take that as some kind of convention, in order Blender keeps coherency in its behavior.

So here, just apply scale, as described in the main answer.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up :)