# A question about the black magic called Apply Scale/Location/Rotation

Tags: modeling

While trying to recreate certain hard surface subjects, I ran into the problem that my mesh didn't accept the bevel modifier, no matter how much I tried to tweak the settings. Then I read here in one of many threads about the similar issue and found out about that magic operation "Apply Scale", which completely solved the problem. I've been blessed with this black magic countless times, but every single time it left me wonder about its the underlying principle.

So, what's the secret? My guess is the bevel modifier source code involves the usage of the scale parameter. But how? I can't see it clearly how it uses those values.

Also, I would like to get control over this black magic. What materials should I read to understand which modifiers involve which parameters (scale/rotation/location) and how they make use of them underneath? I'm willing to venture into the realm of computer graphics theory to defeat this black magic!

Comment: The answer should be nearly the same as this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147373/uv-layout-doesnt-match-shape-of-the-object/147381#147381 as the reasons are the same. Bevel uses internal (mesh level, not object level) geometry for its calculations.

Comment: @lemon: Thank you, Master Lemon! Could you recommend me some materials to learn more about which modifiers use mesh level data, which modifiers use object level data? The link embedded in the "see this documentation" in the answer above yours doesn't work.

Comment: @lemon: A side question, could you also recommend some materials for me to learn more about origin & pivot point and about which operations involves origin, which operations involve pivot point? This is also the problem that confuses me the most.

Comment: I would like to. But my knowledge is mainly empirical. What I can say is modeling (changing shape) should be at mesh level (not object level), if at object level you change rotation or scale for modeling reasons, always think about applying them after (that will avoid issues further). But sorry, I don't have a link that would sum up recipes about all that.